# Oracle SQL String Contains a value from another Table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am looking to find a way to add a where clause where a string in one table contains data from a column in another table.

```
Select
ID,
Name,
Group,
List
From EDG
Where
List Like '% (Select(Column X) FRom Diag)%'
```

I'm looking for something that would work like you see above.  There are no columns to join on for the tables, it is just List in EDG can contain values from column X in Diag.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you can join, because any statement that results in a truth can be used for join:

```
Select
  E.ID,
  E.Name,
  E.LGroup,
  E.List
From 
  EDG E
  INNER JOIN Diag D
  ON
    E.List Like '%'||D.X||'%'
```

Inner join will result in only rows where List string contains X

Comment: Perfect, didn't know that.  Thank you.  Will accept in 3 minutes when it allows me.

Comment: You can even join on things that aren't in any table.. `x JOIN y ON EXTRACT(year from sysdate) = 2019` will join every row in x to every row in y, but only for the next ~45 days, after which.. no results. Of course it's a nonsense joint condition but it demonstrates the point that "anything that evaluates to a Boolean can be used in the ON"